# UIView CALayer border radius background opacity

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a `UITableView` with many `UITableViewCell`s in it. Each one has some simple custom graphics I made using `UIView`s with rounded corners. I'm experiencing bad performance when scrolling on older iPads (2nd and 3rd generation) and after turning on **Debug > Color Blended Layers** in the iOS Simulator I can see that the the part of the UIView that is removed by the rounded corner is left transparent, I think this is causing the bad scrolling performance.

Below are some screen shots to help understand the problem.

What I'd like to know is how I can make opaque the outer part of the `UIView` that is 'cut out' to make the round corners (the orange coloured part in the second screenshot), so as to increase performance. Specifically, is there any property of my `UIView` or its layer property that allow me to make this part opaque?

[image: A UIView with rounded corners][image: A UIView with rounded corners and Color Blended Layers enabled]

Comment: While you do have some blending, are you sure that it's really the performance problem? The devices can usually handle a fair amount of blending without crossing a performance problem. Remove the rounded corners and measure the performance again. If it doesn't improve, then the real problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Good point, I removed the cornerRadius and it's still slow. It would still be nice to know how to do what I originally asked, though. Maybe it will speed things up a little.

Comment: If it's not your bottleneck, it won't do much to improve your performance. It's not going to be any faster than removing the corner radius altogether. Use Instruments to make measurements and find out where you need to make the improvements instead.

Comment: I've already seen bad table scrolling performance caused by using layer corner radius on cell's image view. Simply setting `imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES` helped pretty significantly

Comment: Thanks Lukas.. I tried `shouldRasterize` and the other property for rasterization scale and I couldn't detect any improvement.